# Image upload into an database gone wrong

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload an image with

```
$userimage = sql_real_escape($_FILES['image']['name'])
```

The form also has username and password fields,and when we go into the insert VALUES section it just doesn't save right when it saves.
Thinking that this is messing up the page since it goes to error 500

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
 $uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $upass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));
$image= mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['name']);
 $name= mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['name']));

 if(sub(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image")
 {
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(image,name) VALUES(,'$image','$name')");
 }

 if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password) VALUES('$uname','$email','$upass',)"))
 {
  ?>
        <script>alert('successfully registered ');</script>
        <?php
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
        <script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>
        <?php
 }
}
?>
```

When it saves the as Blob the file size small like 4 or 7kiB for images even 2mb large.

```
<form method="post" entype="multipart/form-data">
<table align="center" width="30%" border="0">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="User Name" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Your Password" required /></td>
</tr>
<td><input type="file" name="image" placeholder="upload here" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><button type="submit" name="btn-signup">Sign Me Up</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="index.php">Sign In Here</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: It would be awesome if we could see your code and stuff

Comment: What would you call it Detective Holmes?

Comment: Ok Ryan. Sounds legit almost like encrypting or locking ur image. But thats all talk, show me how you do this please.

Comment: Ok ok I can do that. You mean something like this:

ROUGH CODE:
$image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                    $name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
                    $image= file_get_contents($image);
                    $image= base64_encode($image);

And what with all the deprecated php5 statements, like they're all not recommended yet there's like no easy-to-find reference book to show substitute statements or code.
Fred, are you hear to stitch up more horrible sweaters with ur razors yo

Comment: Lol All your talk isn't helping Ryan. Just give me what I need and I'll be on my way. :)

Comment: Fix the code above, and I'll get a better grasp of php better with an explanation and solution. :)

Comment: Thanks for writing back.
Cleaned up for clarity now.
The form used to get the user sign up details works fine when it come to saving names passwords and other text.
Uploading an image is what Im onto next and it quite a pinch.
The php above has a few error as a result of numerous trials.
 If you fix this then Id be good. The database connection and include file is all good, just the image upload and retrieval in the sign up format and order. :)

Comment: Where do I change that? phpAdmin, looks very familiar (E_ALL I mean)

Answer (score 1):

Keeping images in database is not good idea.
Better is upload images to some directory and insert to database same filenames.

Answer (score 0):

The information you provided thusfar isnt sufficient enough to say anything sensible about it.

"it just doesnt save right", what does that mean ? Did the script actually insert a record into the database, though an unusable one, or didnt the (insert)query do anything at all but execute ? Or perhaps the script never even got past the isset($_POST) condition?

Comment: There. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I use to do this back in the days, but I see that the db gets too large too quickly. But, based on assumption, maybe you are not inserting the image as type `blob`.

But as the above comment, it is not a good idea to store image in you db. The best option is to have a writable folder and use, in a php example, `move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $writable_folder . $filename )` and store only the name as string in your db.

Comment: sounds cool, given what ur saying I'd have to manually create a folder inside the main say"images" then link it up with ur code (fine, if Im correct).
though image retrieval would be another story.

Comment: Yes, create a folder and give it read and write permissions. The the image retreiveal is very simple all do is query the image name and then use 'path_to_image/$image_name' to show you image.

But it is best to put that folder somewhere where it won't show the folder path to you main pages

for example if you files are in `/wamp/www/my_website/main`, 
you would create that folder in `/wamp/www/my_website/images`,

Comment: Alright, thats done.
Its inside the respective local host directory. Changed the learner code to 

$image( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $images . $filename )
 

 the insert to php should look like this? :) (Doestnt work, error 500 page)

 if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password,image) VALUES('$uname','$email','$upass','$image')"))

Comment: I will answer as a post because it is too long for here

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you got the right idea..but you should first do the following checks:

1. Upload the image using move_uploaded_file to see if the file has uploaded properly
2. Make sure your insert statements runs properly

**IF** the above two is working fine then do this:

```
if( isset( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ) ) {
        // $filename == whatever you want to name you image. Example : photo1.jpg
        // be sure to save you image name with the extension
        if ( ! @move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], '/wamp/www/my_website/images/' . $filename ))
        {
            return FALSE OR return 'error message';
        }

        // if passed then here is where you put you sql statement
        if( mysql_query( "INSERT INTO users(username,email,password,image) VALUES('$uname','$email','$upass','$filename')"))
            return true;

        return FALSE OR return 'error message';
    }
    else 
        return 'Please select a file'
```

Don't worry if the file is uploaded and the SQL is not stored, which should not happen because you should make sure the above 2 criteria is met, whenever re-uploading, once the image has the same name, it will overwrite it.

So another thing is to make sure that the images **DO NOT** have the same name.

Comment: What I like to do is use the id of the user as the name of the image, this allows you to easily grab the user's photo at any given time because more than likely you will be using the user's id in almost everywhere.

Comment: Edited my question, comment too large for here.

(And what if you have multiple pictures.)

Comment: If there is multiple files all you need to do is use a `foreach` loop. If the form accepts multiple then the data will be an array unless you specifically name all the fields a unique name then you need to do that code for each one seperately